# How to change the size of screens in split.screen mode of R?

Tags: r, layout, plot, split

I want to draw two plots next to each other on a single device. I use `split.screen`, since it is easy to handle. But, it seems that `split.screen()` divides the screen equally.

In my case I'd like to have the right column to be slightly narrower. This is because I leave out the axis labels, , which makes the right plot a bit wider than the left plot:

```
#install.packages("TeachingDemos", dependencies=TRUE)
library(package="TeachingDemos")
# ***********************************************************
#source("subplot_new.R.txt")
# ***********************************************************
# data for all 4 plots
dx = c(1:10)
dy = c(10:1)


toPDF = T


if(toPDF) {
  pdf(file="test.pdf", width=10, height=5)
}
# split the screen into two columns
close.screen(all.screens=T)
split.screen(figs=c(1,2))

# go to screen 1
# ***********************************************************
screen(1)
par(mar=c(4,4,0.1,0.1), las=1)
plot(x = dx, y = dy)


# determine coordinates of subplot region:
x_left_right = grconvertX(c(0,0.5), from='npc')
y_bottom_top = grconvertY(c(0,0.5), from='npc')
# draw rectangle
rect(
  xleft     = x_left_right[1]
  , xright  = x_left_right[2]
  , ybottom = y_bottom_top[1]
  , ytop    = y_bottom_top[2]
  , col = "#efefef"
)
# add a subplot in green
subplot(
  fun={
    plot(x = dx, y = dy, ann = F)
  }
  , type = "fig"
  , x = x_left_right
  , y = y_bottom_top
  , pars = list(
    fg = "green"
    , mar = c(2,2,0,0)
    )
)

# go to screen 2
# ***********************************************************
screen(2)
par(mar=c(4,1,0.1,0.1), las=1)
plot(x = dx, y = dy, yaxt="n")
axis(side=2, labels=F)

# determine coordinates of subplot region:
x_left_right = grconvertX(c(0.6,1), from='npc')
y_bottom_top = grconvertY(c(0.6,1), from='npc')
# draw rectangle
rect(
  xleft     = x_left_right[1]
  , xright  = x_left_right[2]
  , ybottom = y_bottom_top[1]
  , ytop    = y_bottom_top[2]
  , col = "#efefef"
)
# add a subplot in blue
subplot(
  fun={
    plot(x = dx, y = dy, ann = F)
  }
  , type = "fig"
  , x = x_left_right
  , y = y_bottom_top
  , pars = list(fg = "blue", mar = c(2,2,0,0))
)

if(toPDF) {
  dev.off()
}
```

I thought `layout` might work, but probably not in my case, since I need to use the subplot command from the TeachinDomes package.

Is there a package similar to `split.screen` that allows for setting the proportion each column should get from the whole screen? Or is it possible to manipulate the split.screen package tofulfil the task?

I simply want to have the two plots having the same size, without having additional white margins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`split.screen` is in fact very flexible and let's you control the size and position your screens freely. All you need to do is feed it an N-by-4 matrix where each row specify the relative position of the left, right, top and bottom edges.

See `?split.screen` for more details.

```
split.screen(matrix(c(0,.7,  .7,1,  0,0,  1,1), ncol=4))
screen(1)
plot(1, 1)
split.screen(matrix(c(0,0,  1,1,  0,.7,  .4,1), ncol=4), screen=2)
screen(3)
plot(2,2)
screen(4)
plot(3,3)
```

[image]

You can even trip out like this,

```
split.screen(matrix(c(0:2,  4:6,  0:2,  4:6)/6, ncol=4))
screen(1)
plot(1,1)
screen(2)
plot(2,2)
screen(3)
plot(3,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea, how I can reduce the width of the left screen by one margin line and add one margin line to the right screen?

Comment: Use `par("din")/par("csi")` to get the width and height of the device in mex units (lines). On my computer the default size is `c(35, 35)`, so by expressing the left and right edges as `x/35` and `(35-x)/35` I can move the border by any number of lines I want.